# Clearing a form field when page goes back (html / javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, passwords

Do you know when you use in a form the **password field**, like this:

`<input type="password" name="pass">`

And you do a GET or POST submit to the **same page** who have the form and if the user hit back in the browser the password field gets blank. Well thats good, but i need to get blank another form field when the user hit back. Thats because i asking for a captcha and the text field who hold the information entered by the user ramain fill when he hit back, but the captcha image change, and if i dont blank the field the user (*sometimes*) dont get that he needs to re-enter the captcha.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try randomizing input name on each refresh, like:

```
<input type="text" id="CaptchaTextBox" name="captcha[612361]" />
```

Browser will notice that input field is different and will clear the value

**Edit:**

I have better solution: as user typed captcha once, just let him go without typing it second time. Now you know that this user is fairly non-machine so why give him so much to do ;)

Comment: That won't be retrieved on pressing the back button

Comment: Great, this is *way* easier to implement and much more user-friendly!

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript**
window.onload(function() 
{
document.getElementById("CaptchaTextBox").value = '';
});

**html**
<input type="text" id="CaptchaTextBox" name="Captcha" />

**Javascript erases the value of the textbox when the page is loaded**

Comment: This won't suffice, as `onload` is not triggered when returning to a page using the back button

Comment: Well then in that case a new captcha image would not be generated either because this requires communicatino back with the server.

Comment: So what I'm trying to say is that the same captcha image will show so the textbox should contain the correct value.